# Changing View Based on Orientation Change iOS

Tags: ios, ipad

So I have used the following code in a couple of view controllers to implement some custom objects being drawn in different ways depending on the change of orientation.

For some reason, this particular implementation of the following two methods does not work:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
}



- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Are we changing orientations?");
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
        NSLog(@"Landscape!");

        /*

         // Landscape orientation
         [txtLoginID setFrame:CGRectMake(489, 200, 145, 30)];
         [txtPassword setFrame:CGRectMake(489, 235, 145, 30)];
         [loginLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(378, 203, 69, 21)];
         [pwdLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(378, 238, 80, 21)];
         loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(561, 273, 73, 30);

         // Set iPad landscape background
         background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
         [background setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
         [background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadLandscape.jpg"]];
         [self.view addSubview:background];
         */
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
        NSLog(@"Portrait!");

        /*
         // Portrait orientation
         txtLoginID.frame = CGRectMake(367, 254, 145, 30);
         txtPassword.frame = CGRectMake(367, 289, 145, 30);
         loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(256, 257, 69, 21);
         pwdLabel.frame = CGRectMake(256, 292, 80, 21);
         loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(439, 327, 73, 30);

         // Set iPad portrait background
         background.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
         [background setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
         [background setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadPortrait.jpg"]];
         [self.view addSubview:background];
         */
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working? My log statements seem to not produce anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lag, maybe try this method instead:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this without subscribing to notifications directly from your view controller by overriding the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method.  See Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926).

Comment: That worked fine, but is there a way to get rid of the noticeable lag? The changes in position of the views occurs only after the orientation has been changed and not during the change of orientation. Any recommendations?